# Call to undefined method Mage_Customer_Helper_Address::getAttributeValidationClass()

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento installation and getting following error on check out page.

```
Call to undefined method Mage_Customer_Helper_Address::getAttributeValidationClass()
```

I have checked `Mage_Customer_Helper_Address` class for this particular function and also searched in class doc. But I did not see this method in doc too. Can anyone tell me what could be the issue ?

Is it a built in method in Magento ? I'm new to Magento and the version installed on server is  `1.4.2.0` .

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that there is some extension incompatible with the version 1.4.2.0? Because Magento v. 1.7, for instance, does have this method in the `Mage_Customer_Helper_Address` class. You could create an override helper and add this method to it:

```
/**
     * Get string with frontend validation classes for attribute
     *
     * @param string $attributeCode
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAttributeValidationClass($attributeCode)
    {
        /** @var $attribute Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute */
        $attribute = isset($this->_attributes[$attributeCode]) ? $this->_attributes[$attributeCode]
            : Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode);
        $class = $attribute ? $attribute->getFrontend()->getClass() : '';

        if (in_array($attributeCode, array('firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname', 'prefix', 'suffix', 'taxvat'))) {
            if ($class && !$attribute->getIsVisible()) {
                $class = ''; // address attribute is not visible thus its validation rules are not applied
            }

            /** @var $customerAttribute Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute */
            $customerAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', $attributeCode);
            $class .= $customerAttribute && $customerAttribute->getIsVisible()
                ? $customerAttribute->getFrontend()->getClass() : '';
            $class = implode(' ', array_unique(array_filter(explode(' ', $class))));
        }

        return $class;
    }
```

Comment: @Many thanks for the reply. I added the above function to Helper class and next time it shown some other function is missing. After I checked the same class in version 1.7.2 found all these referred functions. But in Magento admin section, it is showing version 1.4.2. I think it is a weird stuff.Do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: There must definitely be an extension not compatible with your Magento version. Recreating the missing functions may only exacerbate the situation. I can only suggest to replace all the code in the getAttributeValidationClass($attributeCode) function with `return '';`. This will be as if the attributeCode in question does not have any validation class.

Comment: Just for completeness Mage_Customer_Helper_Address::getAttributeValidationClass() was added in Magento 1.7.0.0